# SQL Server 2014 with GROUP BY on a timestamp and PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

This is probably quite easy, but I haven't been able to get it so I figured I'd ask.

I am using SQL Server 2014 and have a table with the following columns:

```
id, int
date, datetime
sensorId, varchar(45)
observedObjId, varchar(45)
```

I'd like to have a query where I provide the following inputs:

```
sensorId_1
sensorId_2
startDateTime
endDateTime
intervalAmount
intervalTime
```

and then the output would be a resultset that has the two sensor IDs as columns and each row would be a time between the startDateTime and endDateTime broken out by an interval - say, 5 minutes, 1 hour, 1 day etc. and then the value at the intersection would be the count of the number of observedObjIds that the particular sensor.

I never got to the PIVOT piece of it because I wasn't able to get the GROUP BY part correct. I was messing around with grouping by the `DATEPART(datepart, date)` but that seemed to lose the context of the rest of the date so that didn't pan out very well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the `GROUP BY` like this for a `DAY`-based grouping for example (within dynamic SQL to achieve the dynamic column naming based on the specified Sensors):

```
DECLARE @sensorId_1 INT, 
        @sensorId_2 INT,
        @startDateTime DATETIME,
        @endDateTime DATETIME

-- For example, return data for Sensors 3 and 7 within the month of Feb 2016
SET @sensorId_1 = 3
SET @sensorId_2 = 7
SET @startDateTime = '2016-02-01'
SET @endDateTime = '2016-03-01'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql =
'SELECT CAST([date] AS DATE) AS [Day], 
        SUM(CASE WHEN sensorId = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sensorId_1) + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sensor_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sensorId_1) + ',' +
      ' SUM(CASE WHEN sensorId = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sensorId_2) + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sensor_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sensorId_2) +
' FROM [SensorData] 
  WHERE sensorId IN (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sensorId_1) + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sensorId_2) + ') ' +
' AND [date] >= ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@startDateTime,120),'''') +
' AND [date] < ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@endDateTime,120),'''') +
' GROUP BY CAST([date] AS DATE)
  ORDER BY CAST([date] AS DATE)'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

For an hourly breakdown, I would just alter the @sql definition:

```
SET @sql =
'SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST([date] AS DATE)) + '' '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(HOUR,[date])) + '':00'' AS [Hour], 
        SUM(CASE WHEN sensorId = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sensorId_1) + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sensor_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sensorId_1) + ',' +
      ' SUM(CASE WHEN sensorId = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sensorId_2) + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sensor_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sensorId_2) +
' FROM [SensorData] 
  WHERE sensorId IN (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sensorId_1) + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@sensorId_2) + ') ' +
' AND [date] >= ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@startDateTime,120),'''') +
' AND [date] < ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@endDateTime,120),'''') +
' GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST([date] AS DATE)) + '' '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(HOUR,[date])) + '':00''
  ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST([date] AS DATE)) + '' '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(HOUR,[date])) + '':00'''
```

If you then want to be able to dynamically specify the interval (minute, day, month etc.) and how many units of that interval you wish to include in each "bucket", then you'll need to make this a bit more sophisticated.

I would have a `CASE` statement determining how the dynamic SQL was built depending on the (presumably fairly limited?) set of different intervals you might want to handle, but I'm not familiar with `PIVOT`, so perhaps that could give you a more elegant solution.

Hope that helps with the `GROUP BY` part anyway, sorry if I've totally missed the point and you already understood this element of it!

Answer (score 0):

you want it pivoted over `sensorID`, but grouped by the `intervalAmount * datediff(intervalTime, startDateTime, endDateTime)`?

for the `group by`, try:

```
select
  sensorID,
  @intervalAmount * datediff(@intervalTime, @startDateTime, @endDateTime) as timeSpanGroup,
  count(*)
from
  tbl
where
  date >= @startDateTime and
  date <= @endDateTime and
  sensorId in (@sensorID_1, @sensorID_2)
group by
  sensorID, @intervalAmount * datediff(@intervalTime, @startDateTime, @endDateTime)
```